# Embed tweet with DTCoreText

Tags: ios, twitter, dtcoretext

I'm showing a HTML code using DTCoreText. Everything was working so far, but now I'm receiving embedded tweets inside this HTML code and they're not working.
Tweets are embedding with blockquotes tag as is said in the Twitter documentation, this is an example of what I'm receiving:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="fr">
<p>
Here is the official <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/SPECTRE?src=hash">#SPECTRE</a> teaser poster <a href="http://t.co/3cn3iM6tf1">pic.twitter.com/3cn3iM6tf1</a></div>&mdash; James Bond (@007) <a href="https://twitter.com/007/status/577877246809141248">17 Mars 2015</a>
</blockquote>
```

Only the text is shown.
I've registered a new class in DTCoreText this way:

```
[DTTextAttachment registerClass:[MyBlockquoteClass class] forTagName:@"blockquote"];
```

MyBlockQuoteClass has this constructor:

```
- (id)initWithElement:(DTHTMLElement *)element options:(NSDictionary *)options
{
    self = [super initWithElement:element options:options];

    if (self)
    {
        NSLog(@"THIS IS MY ELEMENT %@", element);
        NSLog(@"THESE ARE MY OPTIONS %@", options);
    }

    return self;
}
```

The constructor is called when the blockquote tag is read but options has only 4 keys related to font color and size and element has a lot of attributes but not useful for me, almost everything is nil, there are no childs, only get class="twitter-tweet" and lang="fr", but there is no way to get the content so I can't embed the blockquote inside a UIWebView as I would like to do.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe there is a better approach using DTCoreText?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

For that to work the following would need to be implemented in DTCoreText:

1. a way for a custom tag handler to surpress the contents of the tag from regular output
2. have the custom MyBlockquoteClass be sent the concatenated raw string contents

Then you could provide your own web view with these contents in the delegate method that lets you set a custom view for a text attachment.

3. You probably would want to also have this working with modern attributes (so that it is compatible with UIKit, e.g. UITextView)